# Change the context of excerpt metabox for the 'New Post' page

Tags: metabox

With the Gutenberg layout, is it possible to adjust the context, or position, of the Excerpt metabox from the sidebar of the 'New Post' or 'Edit Post' admin page, to the main area, i.e. to a 'normal' context?

I believe I could add code to delete the Excerpt metabox and, then, re-add an Excerpt metabox with a 'normal' context?  However, then, if I understand correctly, I would lose the functionality of the get_the_excerpt() function.

Is there a simple way, simply, to change the context of the current Excerpt metabox?

The excerpts are important to our site, and to relegate them to the sidebar is unhelpful.